# How can I change main folders in VUE

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm new in Vue. I just create vue project by `vue create my-project-name`.

works fine.

But how can I change the folder structure? wrap `src` and `public` in `client` folder?

```
app folders:
|-client
  |- src
  |- public
|- package.json
```

and still use all the cli features?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `serve` and `build` scripts in `package.json`:

`vue-cli-service serve` to `vue-cli-service serve client/src`
`vue-cli-service build` to `vue-cli-service build client/src`

And `devServer.contentBase` in `vue.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'client/public')
  }
}
```

Comment: Then I get a `MY_PROJECT_FOLDER\client\src in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.56.1:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./client/src` Any clue on what might go wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Recently stumbled on this issue and found a workaround. Ruslan's method did not work for me, unfortunately.

This is my basic full-stack folder structure.

[image: Basic full-stack folder structure]

In order to get it to work, I added the following to `vue.config.js`

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'client/src/main.js',
      template: 'client/public/index.html'
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/src')
      }
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('copy')
      .use(require('copy-webpack-plugin'), [[{
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/public'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        toType: 'dir',
        ignore: ['.DS_Store']
      }]])
  }
}
```

This should

- Set the correct entry and template files.
- Restore the `@` alias functionality.
- Copy files from the `public` folder to the `dist` folder.

**Resources**

- https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/bc3e4af3c0532d32ad53602546c2a91187b36948/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/app.js#L295-L306

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the exact same thing with @vue/cli 3 and what Ruslan suggests didn't work. Plus, if you check in the doc it is written :

```
Usage: vue-cli-service serve [options]

Options:

  --open    open browser on server start
  --copy    copy url to clipboard on server start
  --mode    specify env mode (default: development)
  --host    specify host (default: 0.0.0.0)
  --port    specify port (default: 8080)
  --https   use https (default: false)
```

I clearly can't imagine how it can works with the sample of code you provided.

Comment: Perhaps you are using an older version of vue-cli

Comment: if you run `vue-cli-service serve --help` then usage looks like this: `vue-cli-service serve [options] [entry]`

Answer (score 0):

@Mintonne answer almost work for me, but had problems with the 'copy' plugin modification. Adapted from an answer on this vue-cli issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1550

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    pages: {
        index: {
            entry: "client/src/main.js",
            template: "client/public/index.html"
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "client/src")
            }
        }
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "client/public")
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.plugin('copy')
            .tap(([pathConfigs]) => {
                var conf = [{
                    from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/public'),
                    to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
                }]
                if (!pathConfigs) {
                    pathConfigs = conf
                } else {
                    pathConfigs.concat(conf)
                }
                return [pathConfigs]
            })
    }
};
```