# vue-cli 3.x - change src and public dirs

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have a project created with vue cli (`vue --version -> 3.0.1.)` It has next file structure:

`|-public
|-src
| ...
|-pakage.json`

I want to add server part using same `package.json`. It will be great to move `src` and `public` folders to `client` folder to have file structure like this:

`|-client
|  |-public
|  |-src
|
|-server
|...
|-package.json`

It should be very simple but I can't find exact example.

P.S.: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50899401/2135344) solution not works - I get `This dependency was not found ./client/src` error.

Comment: Do your client and server get built differently and have different dependencies?

Comment: Yes. I use `express` framework for server. But I want keep all dependencies inside one `package.json` file. There is video example with two separate projects for client and server at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fa4cRMaTDUI but it is much easier for deployment to have one `package.json`